# How to edit php files in Child Theme?

Tags: php, child-theme

I created a child theme and i want to edit a php file. So i copy and paste the php file into the child's theme folder and then i edit it. But it seems that nothing changed in the site preview! In the theme's folder there is a subfolder named "templates". There it is the "slider.php". Before creating the child theme, i tried to edit the parent theme and i made the same changes i made in the cherry and it was correct. I want to make some little changes in some php files but i can't!

I think i find the start of my problem but i really can't understand it. In the WordPress documentation in the Child Theme section, in the "Other Files" paragraph it says: "if this file (slider.php) is not included by any of your template files or functions.php file then you can not override this file by your child theme."

I first try creating the "functions.php" and then inserting this code:

```
<?php require_once( get_stylesheet_directory(). 'templates/slider.php' ); ?>
```

But after uploading the "functions.php" in the child theme an error occured.

I am really confused about this!

What is the way to edit a php file in a child theme?

Comment: that seems to be the correct way. you duplicate the php template file into the child theme and edit it.

Comment: That's what i did but nothing changed! Do i have to do something else from copy-paste-edit-save?

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct template? See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: @Duane, I am sure that i am editing the correct template. In the theme's folder there is a subfolder named "templates". There it is the "slider.php". Before creating the child theme, i tried to edit the parent theme and i made the same changes i made in the cherry and it was correct.

I want to make some little changes in some php files but i can't!

P.S. I use the "Cherry Theme" [link](http://themeforest.net/item/cherry-responsive-news-and-magazine-theme-/3671130?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=bdayh)

Comment: @brasofilo I can't understand what you want me to clarify! It is a slider in the main page (index).

Comment: I mean, improve the text of the Question with the explanations you are giving here in Comments. People shouldn't have to read the Comments to understand the Question.

Comment: @brasofilo Ok I already did it! Thank you! Do you have any thought in your mind about what's the problem?

Comment: @brasofilo I think i find the start of my problem but i really can't understand it. In the WordPress documentation in the Child Theme section, in the "Other Files" paragraph it says: "if this file (slider.php) is not included by any of your template files or functions.php file then you can not override this file by your child theme."

 So what functions.php , the parent's or child's? How can i do what it says?

Comment: As I said, Charitos, go improving the Question itself, maybe I'm not the one who answers this, but the next reader will have much more information if you add it to the Q. The software you use to edit themes should have a global search feature, look out for `slider.php`. Child themes are meant so that you don't ever touch the parent, so yes you'll have to edit the child `functions.php`. :::: *I've removed some of my previous comments to not clutter this thread.*

Comment: The file you're editing is not part of the template hierarchy, you can not override a file in a child theme if it is not part of the template hierarchy. You'll need to come up with your own means of handling custom theme files(such as copying the file, editing, then doing a manual include in the appropriate place).

Comment: @t31os so where is the appropriate place to put the include order? In the functions.php or in the slider.php ?

Comment: I have no idea, it will depend how the theme implements that file. My suggestion is to simply emulate how the parent theme uses that file.

Comment: @t31os can you help me with telling me how to do that?

Comment: @t31os In the index.php there is this code referring to slider.php

`<?php if(bdayh_get_option('feature_slider') == 1){ ?>

  <?php if(bdayh_get_option('slider_type') == 'cycleslider'){ ?>
    <?php require BD_TM .'/slider.php'; ?>
     <?php } else { ?>
    <?php require BD_TM .'/slider-flex.php'; ?>
     <?php } ?>

  <?php } ?>`

If this helps...

Comment: @Charitos - Assuming you want to replicate behaviour in the child theme, copy the index file then rewrite the require path to point at the parent theme's directory holding the slider(or copy the slider to and repoint the require path to use the copy).